# entity framework - Read TPT data using DBSet<T>.SqlQuery

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

For performance considerations, we must use `DbSet<T>.SqlQuery` to retrieve entities from Database. But this entity is a base type for several inherited type. 
Using `EF DbSet` with Linq, when we query it, `EF` instanciates the right type whereas we query base type. And this is well appreciated !

An example:

```
Base type : TreeItem
Derived types : Docs, Folder, Files
```

We create a query other `TreeITem` :

```
from item in DbCtxt.TreeItem
where <predicate>
select item:
```

As a result we get a list of different object, some of them are type of `TreeItem` or `Docs` or `Files`...

But now we want to query using our own SQL query and we do not achieve to get inherited types but only `TreeItem`.

Do you know how can we achieve it ?

Thanks
++
Ludo

Answer (score 0):

In the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696332%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) documentation on `SqlQery` it says:

> The returned entities are always of the type of this set and never of a derived type. If the table or tables queried may contain data for other entity types, then the SQL query must be written appropriately to ensure that only entities of the correct type are returned.

This means that you can only query for derived types separately, like

```
context.Set<Folder>()
       .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM TreeItem WHERE Discriminator = 'folder'")
```

If that means you need to execute three queries it may defeat the purpose of getting the best performance.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I didn't see this comment on documentation. This is a bad news but we'll try to workaround.